# Restoring the Self signed certificate in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, keystore

I would like to get back my self -signed cert which i have deleted unfortunately using following command:
keytool -delete -alias alias_name_selfsigned -keystore "D:\SSL\SSL1\test.keystore"

This is happened after importing of CA certificates given by Certification Authority into the keystore.

Would any one please suggest how can i restore my self signed certificate back to original.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll have to create a new one from scratch.